# Requesting help setting up iPhone for Grandpa - coronavirus

Tags: iphone, ios, remote-control

It is April 2020. Grandpa has been willing to practice social distancing and requested to use FaceTime to keep in touch with the family. I switched his cell over to an iPhone 6.

Without having a chance to thoroughly review iPhone functions and apps in person, I was reluctant to hand over the phone. But then we had an earthquake and then he had multiple power outages. So he needed the phone and it seemed pretty important.

He did surprisingly well with it. For about 1 week. Since then he is constantly silencing his phone, putting it into airplane mode, getting stuck in some random app, etc. Without being there to see what is happening, it’s incredibly difficult and time consuming to talk him through these situations.

I think if I could see his screen I would quickly be able to help him through it. Even better: if I could power cycle, change settings, and most of all close open apps, it would save a lot of time.

I have considered 3rd party apps for remote sharing, but I don’t know enough to choose and or set it up in the first place. Looking for recommendations for

1) At minimum allow me to see his screen so I can walk him through steps over the landline.

2) If possible allow me to remotely control his device from my Mac (running Catalina)

3) I don’t know enough about security but I would like to do this safely if possible.

Comment: There was a very similar thread over on apple discussions. Seems to have been removed.